# DDD and Doctrine mapping inside Entity

Tags: php, zend-framework2, doctrine, domain-driven-design

I want to use Doctrine for data persistence in a Domain Driven Design approach. But what are bothering me is the fact that the association mapping should be inside the entity. Isn't that a bad practice in terms of a pure DDD? Because until I get into the persistence issue, my domain entities were so clean, and now they have a lot of comments in its properties. Like this:

```
<?php

namespace Domain\Model;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class User
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="SEQUENCE")
     * @ORM\SequenceGenerator(sequenceName="user_id_seq", allocationSize=1, initialValue=1)
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;  

    ...
```

Besides using these comments, I also have to have the `use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;`. In that way, the infrastructure are not keeping separate from domain.

Is there some way to move this mapping to a config file? I'm using ZF2.

Comment: Doctrine 2 supports yaml as well as xml mapping.  Just search the ZF2 documents for how to do this in their framework.  I use Symfony 2 so I can't give you specifics but I'm sure it can be done.

Comment: This worked! Thanks for answer. I used this approach for Zend: https://www.kerstner.at/en/2014/04/managing-doctrine-2-entity-model-classes-using-yamldriver-in-zend-framework-2/

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is bad from a DDD perspective. There are two solutions:

- Use an external mapping mechanism, such as the one described by @Cerad. This frees the domain model from persistence concerns, but it may also be a pain to manage. After all, many projects moved away from XML-based persistence configuration for a reason.
- Create a separate persistence model. This model is dead-simple and contains no logic at all, just data. Then, create a mapper to map between the two.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I used the first solution given by @Cerad. About the second solution, should I have 2 entities representing the User? One for domain and another for persistence?

Comment: @RodrigoOtavio Yes, although I wouldn't call the persistence object an entity to avoid confusion.

Comment: Entity is the name used by Doctrine but, yes, with this division the DDD Entity is your Domain-Model, and the Doctrine Entity would be a kind of Persistence DTO (just data, schema definition annotations, no behaviour). – Using XML/YAML for Doctrine schema definitions  would implicitly enforce the difference and would not raise the confusion about having two classes/entities representing the User. Domain is in PHP classes and Doctrine schema is in XML.

Answer (score 0):

Onion Architecture has the answer to your question and is one of the recommended architecture approaches for DDD. The idea I that you keep Domain Layer only contains business logic. The infrasctruture layer will have the repository. It the job of the repository to persist the changes made in the domain objects. Hence, if you are using ORM, this is the layer where you should maintain your mapping. Here's is a [great post](https://codingcraft.wordpress.com/2015/10/12/implementing-repository-in-ddd-part-1/) on how to implement Repository in DDD, hope it helps,

https://codingcraft.wordpress.com/2015/10/12/implementing-repository-in-ddd-part-1/